# How to generate a class diagram in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, class-diagram, jetbrains-toolbox

I installed the simpleUMLCE plugin for code analysis.

But I keep getting this error Plugin "simpleUMLCE" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)... And simpleUMLCE doesn’t work.

The simpleUMLCE tab does not appear on the left, and it is not installed even if you look at File> Settings> Plugin.

There is no problem using Android Studio, but I hope this error does not come out.

How can I fix it?

Comment: i don't know anything about this plugin specifically, but if it says `supported only in IntelliJ IDEA` then i'm not sure if it'll work in android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

The https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4946-simpleumlce plugin isn't compatible with the recent Intellij IDEA and Android Studio version.
The last version of that plugin is from 2010.

It's nothing you can do about.

**Other solution**
Intellij IDEA Ultimate supports generating diagrams out of the box.